# Are cookies cached?

Tags: java, cookies

I want to delete *all* the cookies from a signed Java applet. I remove Cookie file, and all the cache files, but the cookies are still there in the browser (tested at his [cookie test page](http://www.html-kit.com/tools/cookietester/)).

Are the cookies cached? Can I actually remove them *without restarting the brwser*?

**System info:**

OS X + Chrome

Comment: Chrome has a built-in developer console to do this. You can refresh and delete but don't know about editing. Press F12 -> Resources -> Cookies

Comment: I want to do it from app level, automatically

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so cookies are being cached. Also, there is no need to restart the browser in this case.

I checked with firefox on the link you gave. Cookies are being cleared normally. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I tested it on both FF and chrome (OS X) and deleting the cookies *do not affect instantly* the browser: when I delete the file, and refresh the page, the cookie is *still detected*...